# Getting output of 2 numbers after the decimal point

Tags: java

New to java, i am trying to get output of variables grossPayConv, taxesConv and netPayConv to have the output of XX.XX(having 2 places after the decimal). i believe i am casting wrong or something. i keep getting numbers with no values after the decimal. thanks, sorry for the basic question, can't seem to get it.

P.S = if your curious about the variable names... Conv - meaning conversion

```
System.out.println("hours worked: ");
double hours = input2.nextDouble();

System.out.println("hourly pay rate: ");

double payHours = input3.nextDouble(); 
double grossPay = payHours*hours;
double grossPayConv = (int)(grossPay*100)/100;
double taxes = grossPay*TX;
double taxesConv = (int)(taxes * 100) / 100;
double netPay = grossPay-taxes;
double netPayConv = (int)(netPay*100)/100;
```

Comment: google about DecimalFormat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you casting the output to int.Update as below :

```
double grossPayConv = (grossPay*100)/100;
```